# Is it possible to crash the Internet?

Tags: attacks, ddos

Could a skilled hacker given the resources crash the internet itself? With more and more people joining the internet everyday, it would be becoming increasingly easier for hackers to just, overload the internet and crash it, or at least make it become extremely slow to the point it's unusable. I don't even know whether it's possible but it does beg the question, will the internet one day become unsustainable, to the point that it can be abused by hackers and just, crashed?

Comment: Also, take a look at [any of these posts tagged with 'ddos'](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ddos?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Comment: @Polynomial the question isn't crashing part of the internet nor slowing it down, It's about crashing the the internet itself, as the title clearly explains.

Comment: @Polynomial The questions clearly have different answers, as this question is about the whole internet meaning every server and everything connected online, the other question is about most servers.

Comment: @Polynomial "will the internet one day become unstable/" could have a logical answer

Comment: @JakeWickham It's speculation at best, which doesn't fit StackExchange. I suggest both of you read the [don't ask](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page.

Comment: @MountainSideStudios Then the answer is a worldwide extinction event, since the only sure way to power off every electronic device on the planet with communications capability is to destroy every device on the planet with communications capability. This is not a security question.

Comment: @MountainSideStudios Perhaps instead of rejecting criticism of your question, you should take a moment to consider whether [the third highest reputation user on the site](http://security.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) telling you that your question is not suitable here might carry some merit. I understand that it's not fun to be told your question isn't appropriate, but the rules are here for a reason: without them, the site would become an unintelligible mess of opinion and discussion rather than fact. StackExchange is not a forum.

Comment: @Polynomial I withdraw my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, the internet would be susceptible to a ddos attack, just like every other thing that revolves around connections. Servers have a finite amount of memory/voices, both of which could be filled therefore crashing/dramatically slowing the internet to the point of connections being impossible. Hopefully this answers your question

Also to crash the internet you would have to attack every single server that hosts a website. You have to infect all of them with malware or a super massive DDOS attacking all IPs

A simple [google search](https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl#q=can+the+internet+be+crashed) returned these links:

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000085.htm

http://www.cnn.com/2012/07/10/tech/web/internet-down-eagleman/

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/internet-collapse4.htm